# $d(Tx, Ty) < d(x, y)$ does not guarantee existence of fixed point.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $T$ be a mapping of a complete metric space $X$ into itself. How do I show that the condition $d(Tx, Ty) < d(x, y)$, where $x \neq y$, does not suffice for the existence of a fixed point for $T$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the example of the real map $x \mapsto \sqrt{x^2+1}$.

You have more details [here.](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/counterexample-banach-fixed-point-theorem/)